# Automatic Login in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I have a login interface as below in an app that I am working on that is working with parse as database. I want the app to log in automatically for the user in the next time when a users opens the app again unless the user clicks the log-out button to remove the password (which is seen as secure view). How can I do this?

```
@IBAction func signInBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(emailTxt.text, password: passwordTxt.text) {
        (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            println("logIn")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoMainVCFromSigninVC", sender: self)

        } else {

            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong username or password", message: "Please try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use keychain to save last username and password which was signed in. Then make a check when you load the app whether the user quit the app in signed in state. You can save the user's state in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: is there any tutorial or documentation for this in swift. I do not know how to store data in the keychain?

Comment: @saner https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift , recommend to store in keychain instead of NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score -2):

You can save any data using UserDefaults so:

```
var save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

save.setValue(someVariable, forKey: "keyForSavedVariable")
save.synchronize()
```

Load data using

```
var save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
someVariable=save.valueForKey("keyForSavedVariable")
```

You can add "as! NSString" or other type strings to the last line

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not safe. https://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/